# How to structure projects sharing the same base/common libraries?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, architecture

So I'm working on a project, which currently consists of two parts.

One is a desktop application.
The other is a server-side application.

Both of these applications share some common libraries.

As of now, I have both of them in the same project, but I am wondering if I maybe should split them up.

How does someone handle this?

What I can think of actually having 3 projects one containing the common libraries and one for server and another for the desktop part. And then you build the common libraries push them to your local maven repo and can include them in both?

Now I just can include them via compile("common library") and the common libraries then just get compiled if there were changes. With the other approach, I would have to compile the common libraries every time separately.

I was just wondering how in business/enterprise applications such things are handled and if there are some architectural patterns for such problems?

Comment: just use https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html ! it perfectly meets your need.  create e.g. `common`, `server` and `desktop` subprojects ( see examples here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html ). common configuration shared by these 3 subprojects can be centralized in the root project build script.

Comment: Yea but the thing is i don't whant sub projects i want to split them completely, i want to have two seperate code bases for server/desktop. Thats what the questsion was abount i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate them into three different projects and use Gradle Composite Build when you want to develop (some of) them together. Composite Build provides better isolation than multi project build, and scales well when you have larger and larger setups.